# convert float to int handling Nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv as shown below:

```
db,date,RequestCount,ScheduledCount,PerformedCount,Product
abc,2020-06-01 00:00:00.000,51,22,37,xyz
abc,2020-06-02 00:00:00.000,,11,19,xyz
abc,2020-06-03 00:00:00.000,52,20,36,xyz
abc,2020-06-04 00:00:00.000,37,12,17,xyz
abc,2020-06-05 00:00:00.000,57,23,39,xyz
abc,2020-06-08 00:00:00.000,37,13,28,xyz
abc,2020-06-09 00:00:00.000,48,16,31,xyz
abc,2020-06-10 00:00:00.000,60,24,40,xyz
abc,2020-06-11 00:00:00.000,35,11,,xyz
```

I am reading it with pandas(`pd.read_csv`). Since there are two `NaN` here, the columns `RequestCount` and `PerformedCount` are converted into `float64`.

But I need all the numeric columns to be of type `integer`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried this,

1. `astype(int)` - Failing at Nan Values.

Comment: Then do a preprocessing pass where you convert `,,` to `,0,`.  You can use `sed` for that; no programming required.

Comment: You can use `.astype('Int64')` or `.astype('Int32')`

Comment: @TimRoberts Making changes in CSV is not in my control.

Comment: My pandas is rusty but try `df.RequestCount.fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: Come on, use your imagination.  You don't have to overwrite the files.  You can do the preprocessing to a temp file, or even to a string in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.astype({'RequestCount':'Int64', 'ScheduledCount':'Int64', 'PerformedCount':'Int64'})
```

---

**Update**

Or:

```
df=pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
df[['RequestCount','ScheduledCount','PerformedCount']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.astype({'RequestCount':'Int64', 'ScheduledCount':'Int64', 'PerformedCount':'Int64'})
```

Comment: fillna is also adding 0 in case a string value is None. in above csv, if db is None, it will add 0 there(which is int) but the type of db is string.

Comment: @AmanRaheja, if you wish to only affect specific columns you can do so by replacing `df.filna(0, inplace=True)` with `df[['RequestCount','ScheduledCount','PerformedCount']].filna(0, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pandas ≥1.0, you can benefit from the new [nullable integer type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df['RequestCount'] = df['RequestCount'].astype('Int64')
```

*NB. note the capital `I` in `Int64`*

output:

```
    db                     date  RequestCount  ScheduledCount  PerformedCount Product
0  abc  2020-06-01 00:00:00.000            51              22            37.0     xyz
1  abc  2020-06-02 00:00:00.000          <NA>              11            19.0     xyz
2  abc  2020-06-03 00:00:00.000            52              20            36.0     xyz
3  abc  2020-06-04 00:00:00.000            37              12            17.0     xyz
4  abc  2020-06-05 00:00:00.000            57              23            39.0     xyz
5  abc  2020-06-08 00:00:00.000            37              13            28.0     xyz
6  abc  2020-06-09 00:00:00.000            48              16            31.0     xyz
7  abc  2020-06-10 00:00:00.000            60              24            40.0     xyz
8  abc  2020-06-11 00:00:00.000            35              11             NaN     xyz
```

```
>>> df['RequestCount'].isna()
0    False
1     True
2    False
...
```

Comment: thanks for the soln, how can I convert `<NA>' to None?, as I need to <NA> in my result. None works.

Comment: @AmanRaheja - You can't have `None` values in a column of type `int`.

Comment: Well, you could have `None`, but this would convert to object type and you would lose all the benefits from vectorization (so in summary, don't)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny what is not correct?

Comment: Well you cannot use `None` in `fillna`, but you can `replace` NAs with `None`, or create a Series of integers and None (`pd.Series([1,2,None], dtype='object')`) but the dtype will be object, not int. I never said you can have `None` and dtype int ;)